# Cplex Studio Does not support dvar float

Tags: cplex

I am trying to use a variable to record the local timings of an object. As I could not find any way to define a variable in the Cplex, I tried using "dvar float" to define the variable. But, Cplex says that the algorithm does not support "dvar float". I tried simply define the variable as float Z[i][r][k] and also tried using CP, both did not solve the issue. May I have some help or guidance please?

```
i = 0..3;
r = 0..1;
j = 0..3;
s = 0..1;
k = 1; 
float U[1..3][1..1] = ...;
float T[i][r][j][s] = ...;
float M[1..3][1..1] = ...; 
dvar boolean X[i][r][j][s][k];
dvar boolean Y[1..N][1..H][k];
dvar float Z[i][r][k];

forall(ci in i:ci!=0, cr in r:cr!=0, cj in j, cs in s: (ci!=cj)||(cr!=cs), ck in k)
  TimeRecord1: 
    Z[cj][cs][ck] == X[ci][cr][cj][cs][ck] * (T[ci][cr][cj][cs] + (U[ci][cr] + (M[ci][cr] - Z[ci][cr][ck])) * Y[ci][cr][ck]);
```

Comment: Are you using CPLEX or CP? I ask because CPLEX definitely does allow dvar float. Look at some of the OPL examples, such as blending.

Comment: I think I am using CP. Sorry, I am really new to CPLEX studio. I think CPLEX could use dvar float but CP cannot.

Answer (score 0):

with CP, float decision variables are not allowed.
What you can do is use a variable change to model decimal decision variables.
You have an example in

> CPLEX_Studio1210\opl\examples\opl\floatexpr

See also [CPLEX OPL using decision variable as float in constraint programming algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334041/cplex-opl-using-decision-variable-as-float-in-constraint-programming-algorithm)

within stackoverflow